# Exporting CircuiTikZ drawings to png

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-external

I have 3 CircuiTikZ drawings that I want to export as 600 dpi png files. How can I do this? Now my LaTeX file looks like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
      \begin{circuitikz}
         stuff...
      \end{circuitikz}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
      \begin{circuitikz}
         stuff...
      \end{circuitikz}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
      \begin{circuitikz}
         stuff...
      \end{circuitikz}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

(I am using LaTeX on macOS)

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The `standalone` class allows for PNG generation (using an external software). Try replacing `\documentclass{article}` with `\documentclass[multi=circuitikz,ignorerest,png]{standalone}` and hope for the best. It's not meant to extract a lot of diagrams from full documents, but rather be used on sub-files, i.e. having a `standalone` document for each diagramm.

Comment: Also, some other notes: 1) `\begin{figure}[h!]` is not good style, as it is intended as a *float*, not as a static thing, and not very useful anyway if there is no `\caption` (which you might have in your real document).  2) Don't use `{center}` environment here, but the `\centering` macro. The environment is more text paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your code a bit, removing the `figure` and `center` environments, you can use the `standalone` class as shown below. Note `\standaloneenv{circuitikz}` to make `standalone` aware of that environment.

The automatic conversion, enabled by the `convert` class option, requires that ImageMagick is installed, and that you run the document with `shell-escape` enabled, e.g. `pdflatex  --shell-escape filename.tex`.

The document below creates three `.png` files called `filename-0.png`, `filename-1.png` and `filename-2.png`, looking like this:

[image: img1] [image: img2][image: img3]

```
\documentclass[convert={density=600}]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_1$] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_2$] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_3$] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that `\standaloneenv{circuitikz}` can be replaced by a class option `multi=circuitkz`. (`multi=<env>` calls  `\standaloneenv{<env>}` internally and `\standaloneenv` enabled `multi` if not yet done)

Comment: Also `standalone` has the `ignorerest` option to ignore everything except the `standaloneenv`s, but I don't expect it to work if the environments are inside other groups.

Comment: It works just perfect. Thank very much for your clear answer!